# Mapping a list of Debian packages in a specific order of 2nd list with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to map a list of files to a list of filenames.  The goal is to install Debian files in specific order (base off the list of names).  I can retrieve the list of files with a shell command and register them to a list.  The goal is to generate a list of filenames in the order of my predefined name list.  Then install them in that order.

ms2Num.stdout_lines is the list of files from the shell command:

```
# use List -1 to find the file names for the deb files.| grep
- name: Find the needed deb files
  shell: "ls -1 {{ DestDir | join }}/ms2install/ms2install/ | grep {{ ms2Num.stdout_lines[0] | join }}"
  register: ProviderDebList
```

This task generates a list `ProviderDebList.stdout_lines`.
Here is the list of files:

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        "ms2-apache_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-ctps_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-desert_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-provider_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-w3gui_1.6.1.8+1~20160324_amd64.deb"
    ]
```

Mapping task

```
- name: Display files in order from MS2-list
  debug:
    msg: "File name: {{ ms2Num.stdout_lines | regex_search( item | string ) | string }}"
  loop: "{{ MS2Packages }}"
```

Running the mapping task I get:
But I get an error:

```
fatal: [10.0.2.25]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on (File name: {{ ms2Num.stdout_lines | regex_search( item | string ) | string }}): expected string or buffer"
```

My knowledge of the Ansible's filters fairly basic so these errors are still a pain to parse.   I know that I'm missing something, but what?

#### Goal:

The goal is to generate a list of filenames in the order of the `MS2Packages`.
I want to take my name list and map the filenames order it.

Here is the list to base the installation order to:

```
MS2Packages:
  - ms2-desert
  - ms2-ctps
  - ms2-apache
  - ms2-w3gui
  - ms2-provider
    ]
```

The resulting list should be:

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        "ms2-desert_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-ctps_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-apache_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
        "ms2-w3gui_1.6.1.8+1~20160324_amd64.deb"
        "ms2-provider_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
    ]
```

Some of the later files use the earlier ones as dependencies so I need to install them in a specific order.

## Working task: (Solved)

```
# print the files names in order of the deb list
- name: Create the list files in order from MS2-list
  set_fact:
    OrderProviderList: "{{ OrderProviderList | default([]) + ProviderDebList.stdout_lines | map('regex_search', '.*' + order + '.*') | select('string') | list }}"
  loop: "{{ MS2Packages }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: order
```

I can now loop through this list and install the needed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to apply `regex_search` filter on your list of packages names (`ProviderDebList`) in a loop of "order list" (`MS2Packages`) is actually a good one. What you miss is that you have to apply the `regex_search` filter with [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map) (which will apply the filter on each item of your list).

So here is the working solution:

```
- name: List sorting
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    MS2Packages:
      - ms2-desert
      - ms2-ctps
      - ms2-apache
      - ms2-w3gui
      - ms2-provider
    ProviderDebList:
      - ms2-apache_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb
      - ms2-ctps_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb
      - ms2-desert_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb
      - ms2-provider_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb
      - ms2-w3gui_1.6.1.8+1~20160324_amd64.deb

  tasks:
    - name: Print package in the right order
      debug:
        msg: " - {{ ProviderDebList | map('regex_search', '.*'+order+'.*') | select('string') | list }}"
      loop: "{{ MS2Packages }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: order
```

Comment: Almost works.  I needed to add the `.stdout_lines` to the Deb list.
`msg: "- {{ ProviderDebList.stdout_lines | map('regex_search', '.*' + order + '.*') | select('string') | list }}" `
That worked.  I got the list of files in the order I needed.

Comment: Indeed, I simulated your files and package lists input in my test playbook.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    my_pkg: "{{ my_pkg|default([]) +
                ms2Num.stdout_lines|
                select('search', item)|
                list }}"
  loop: "{{ MS2Packages }}"
- debug:
    var: my_pkg
```

give

```
"my_pkg": [
    "ms2-desert_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
    "ms2-ctps_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
    "ms2-apache_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb", 
    "ms2-w3gui_1.6.1.8+1~20160324_amd64.deb", 
    "ms2-provider_1.6.1.8~20160324_amd64.deb"
]
```